# Выборка с каждой строки select запроса и присвоение значения переменной

Tags: c#, sql

Пример таблицы 'table':

|table1----|----table2|----table3----|

|------------|------------|----------------|

|User------|  5000-----|-15-02-2016|

|admin----|  3500-----|-18-03-2016|

|guest-----|  2000-----|-15-02-2016|

Делаю запрос:

```
SELECT  *
FROM table
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),table3,102) LIKE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),15-02-2016,102)
```

Запрос выдает мне:

```
|User------|  5000-----|-15-02-2016|
|guest-----|  2000-----|-15-02-2016|
```

На самом деле запрос мне выдает намного больше строк и надо пройтись циклом в каждой строке этого запроса и работать над полученными данными. Для облегчение понимание напишу чуть понятнее

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= _selectedRowCount- 1; i++)
        {
            string s= //тут данный с столбца table1 i строки запроса
            int ammount=//тут данный с столбца table2 i строки запроса
            //
            //... работа с полученными данными
            //
        }
```

Как можно будет реализовать что то на подобии этого? В общем, нужно пройтись по каждой строке запроса по очереди. Обработанные данные передаются в внешний источник. Точнее в Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос на свой случаи так:

```
WITH MyTable AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY table1) AS RowNum, *
FROM   table
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),table3,102) LIKE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),15-02-2016,102)
)
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable .RowNum=2
```

Этот запрос выполняю внутри цикла но за место

```
 RowNum=2
```

ставлю

```
 RowNum=i
```

и получаю каждую строку запроса по одной и работаю сним как и хотел. Может кому и поможет мой способ. Если есть более правильный подход то хотелось бы посмотреть.

Comment: Задосите свой сервер, скорее всего. Лучше взять данные одним запросом, а уже на клиенте обработать.

Comment: Вы правы. Тогда придется придумать куда лучше забрать и как обработать. Надо на C# забирать

Comment: Давайте начнем, вот с чего, что вы используете, для связи с базой данных (DataReader, DataSet, EF, LinqToSQL...). Когда у вас на руках будет некий набор данных, его уже легко будет обработать с помощью Linq, и записать куда вы там пишите.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть `query` результат вашего запроса, тогда:

```
var result = query.Select(element => new { s = element[table1], amount = element[table2]});
```

`result` уже передаем во внешний источник